# c++ wait_until strange timeout behaviour

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11

I'm trying to write a kind of thread pool in C++. The code works fine in OSX, but under Linux I'm experiencing a strange behavior. 
After a bit of debugging, I found the problem is due to a call to std::condition_variable::wait_until that I must be doing in a wrong way.

With the code below I expect the loop to be looped once every three seconds:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock                           my_clock;
typedef std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1> >        seconds_duration;
typedef std::chrono::time_point<my_clock, seconds_duration> timepoint;

timepoint my_begin = my_clock::now();

float timepointToFloat(timepoint time) {
  return time.time_since_epoch().count() - my_begin.time_since_epoch().count();
}

void printNow(std::string mess) {
  timepoint now = my_clock::now();
  cout << timepointToFloat(now) << " " << mess  << endl;;
};

void printNow(std::string mess, timepoint time ) {
  timepoint now = my_clock::now();
  cout << timepointToFloat(now) << " " << mess  << " " << timepointToFloat(time) << endl;;
};

int main() {
  mutex _global_mutex;
  condition_variable _awake_global_execution;
  auto check_predicate = [](){
    cout << "predicate called" << endl;
    return false;
  };

  while (true) {
    { // Expected to loop every three seconds
      unique_lock<mutex> lock(_global_mutex);
      timepoint planned_awake = my_clock::now() + seconds_duration(3);
      printNow("wait until", planned_awake);
      _awake_global_execution.wait_until(lock, planned_awake, check_predicate);
    }
    printNow("finish wait, looping");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, sometimes I get as output:

```
<X> wait until <X+3>
predicate called
(...hangs here for a long time)
```

(where X is a number), so it seems the timeout is not scheduled after three seconds. Sometimes instead I get:

```
<X> wait until <X+3>
predicate called
predicate called
<X> finish wait, looping
<X> wait until <X+3> (another loop)
predicate called
predicate called
<X> finish wait, looping
(...continue looping without waiting)
```

so it seems the timeout is scheduled after a small fraction of seconds. I think I'm messing up something with the timeout timepoint, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

If it may be relevant, this code works fine in OSX, while in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4, compiled with "g++ main.cc -std=c++11 -pthread") I'm experiencing the strange behavior.

How can I get it work?

Comment: Before you wait, you need to make sure the thing you're waiting for has not already happened. And before you decide not to wait, you must make sure the thing you're waiting for has already happened. Condition variables are stateless and have no idea what you're waiting for or whether it's happened. It's your job to keep track.

Comment: Have you tried to cast your timeout to your clock duration`std::chrono::duration_cast<my_clock::duration>(seconds_duration(3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast your timeout to your clock's duration:

```
auto planned_awake = my_clock::now() + 
                     std::chrono::duration_cast<my_clock::duration>(secon‌​ds_duration(3));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works!! I previously tried to cast it as follows:

    "timepoint planned_awake = my_clock::now() + std::chrono::duration_cast<my_clock::duration>(secon‌​ds_duration(3));"

but it made no difference. Using the auto keyword instead of timepoint is working instead. But why?

Comment: I‘m not sure, but although manipulating different durations works fine and fail by narrowing conversions, time_points are not so sensitive. It will work if you use ˋmy_clock::time_pointˋ.